# Overloading fails when Manifest (or TypeTag) implicit parameters in use?

Tags: scala

Consider the following (useless) higher order function that seeks to access the Manifests of its passed function's parameters:

```
def foo[T <: (P1) => Unit, P1](f: T)(implicit p1: Manifest[P1]) {}
```

Here's an example which compiles fine:

```
def theFunc(i: Int) {}
def foo[T <: (P1) => Unit, P1](f: T)(implicit p1: Manifest[P1]) {}
foo(theFunc _)
```

Let's say we want to add an overload that supports functions of two parameters as well:

```
def theFunc(i: Int) {}
def foo[T <: (P1) => Unit, P1](f: T)(implicit p1: Manifest[P1]) {}
def foo[T <: (P1, P2) => Unit, P1, P2](f: T)(implicit p1: Manifest[P1], p2: Manifest[P2]) {}
foo(theFunc _)
```

.. compiler says not so fast:

```
overloaded method value foo with alternatives:
[error]   [T(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo) <: (P1, P2) => Unit, P1, P2](f: T(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo))(implicit p1: Manifest[P1], implicit p2: Manifest[P2])Unit <and>
[error]   [T(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo) <: P1 => Unit, P1](f: T(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo)(in method foo))(implicit p1: Manifest[P1])Unit
[error]  cannot be applied to (Int => Unit)
[error]     foo(theFunc _)
[error]     ^
[error] one error found
```

Ok, what if we remove the Manifest implicit parameters?

```
def theFunc(i: Int) {}
def foo[T <: (P1) => Unit, P1](f: T) {}
def foo[T <: (P1, P2) => Unit, P1, P2](f: T) {}
foo(theFunc _)
```

Compiles fine again!

What about using some differently typed implicit parameters?

```
def theFunc(i: Int) {}
def foo[T <: (P1) => Unit, P1](f: T)(implicit i: Int) {}
def foo[T <: (P1, P2) => Unit, P1, P2](f: T)(implicit i: Int, s: String) {}

implicit val i = 3
implicit val s = "hi"

foo(theFunc _)
```

Also compiles fine.

Anyone know what's going on here?  I'm running Scala 2.10.0.  I tried swapping TypeTags for Manifests and got the same errors, so I'm guessing it's specific to compiler supplied implicits.

Note that I'm pretty sure defining T as a type parameter is required for my true use case, because I need its TypeTag; I don't believe the existential types alternative proposed below will work.

[Here's my actual code in case anyone's interested -- it's an abstraction over jsonCall in Lift to create AnonFunc JsExps from Scala functions.](https://gist.github.com/9840ae5a37d4b03c759a)

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**: Why can't I use existential types as Régis Jean-Gilles recommends?

In my real use case linked to above, I also need the TypeTag of the function being passed.  What I pass isn't an anonymous function, but an object that extends Function2:

```
object MyFunc extends ((Int, String) => JsCmd) {
  def apply(myInt: Int, myString: String) = JsCmds.Noop
}
```

This allows me to read the function's parameter names via the TypeTag ([see the gist](https://gist.github.com/9840ae5a37d4b03c759a)).

Exercising some naïveté about existential types, I tried this:

```
object MyFunc extends ((Int, String) => Unit) {
  def apply(myInt: Int, myString: String) {}
}

def foo[P1, P2, T](f: T forSome { type T <: (P1, P2) => Unit})(implicit tag: TypeTag[T],  p1: Manifest[P1], p2: Manifest[P2]) = tag

foo(MyFunc)
```

Which of course yields:

```
<console>:12: error: type parameter not specified
                  foo(MyFunc)
                     ^
```

---

If I'm abusing the type system just stop me now, but **if there isn't a satisfactory answer to the original issue of the overloads, doesn't this feel like a compiler bug?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question is why do you have such complex type parameters? Looking at your example, it seems that you could very well turn these defintition:

```
def foo[T <: (P1) => Unit, P1](f: T)(implicit p1: Manifest[P1]) {}
def foo[T <: (P1, P2) => Unit, P1, P2](f: T)(implicit p1: Manifest[P1], p2: Manifest[P2]) {}
```

into the much simpler definitions:

```
def foo[P1](f: P1 => Unit)(implicit p1: Manifest[P1]) {}
def foo[P1, P2](f: (P1, P2) => Unit)(implicit p1: Manifest[P1], p2: Manifest[P2]) {}
```

With the latter, the call to `foo` compiles fine.

If for some reason you really need the type `T` (by example your actual code defines types that extend functions **and** your `foo` methods return something that depends on the exact type of function), you could rely on existential types:

```
def foo[P1](f: T forSome { type T <: (P1) => Unit})(implicit p1: Manifest[P1]) {}
def foo[P1, P2](f: T forSome { type T <: (P1, P2) => Unit})(implicit p1: Manifest[P1], p2: Manifest[P2]) {}
```

As for why you get an error in the first place, I have honestly no conclusive explaination.

---

**UPDATE**: OK, so from your comment below it seems that my intuition was good: you over-simplified your example, as you actually **do need** the type parameter T.

I says **seems** because in all honesty I can't see how your `TypeTag[T]` will get you anywhere in the gist you have posted. Looking at the code, you apparently use the `TypeTag` only to try to extract parameter names. The problem is that you're actually getting the parameter names of the `apply` method of function objects. In other words, you will always get `v1`, `v2` and so on (see by example the definition of `Function2`: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function2) regardless of whether the function objects wraps a method with different parameter names.

That said, I'll assume from now that you do need to get a `TypeTag` for the function type.
There is actually no problem with the first solution I gave above (the one without `T` parameter at all), so you might want to try again. Illustration:

```
def foo[P1](f: P1 => Unit)(implicit tag: TypeTag[P1 => Unit], p1: Manifest[P1]) { println( "TypeTag: " + tag ) }
def foo[P1, P2](f: (P1, P2) => Unit)(implicit tag: TypeTag[(P1, P2) => Unit], p1: Manifest[P1], p2: Manifest[P2]) { println( "TypeTag: " + tag ) }
foo(theFunc _)
```

Result:

```
TypeTag: TypeTag[Int => Unit]
```

Seems OK to me. So I would advise to just use that.

Note that with existentials, this won't compile at all (so I don't know where you managed to get `Any`):

```
def foo[P1](f: T forSome { type T <: (P1) => Unit})(implicit tag: TypeTag[T],  p1: Manifest[P1]) {}
def foo[P1, P2](f: T forSome { type T <: (P1, P2) => Unit})(implicit tag: TypeTag[T],  p1: Manifest[P1], p2: Manifest[P2]) {}

<console>:15: error: not found: type T
          def foo[P1, P2](f: T forSome { type T <: (P1, P2) => Unit})(implicit tag: TypeTag[T],  p1: Manifest[P1], p2: Manifest[P2]) {}
                                                                                            ^
<console>:14: error: not found: type T
          def foo[P1](f: T forSome { type T <: (P1) => Unit})(implicit tag: TypeTag[T],  p1: Manifest[P1]) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply! I don't have prior experience with existential types.  I do end up taking the TypeTag of T in my real use case, and adding it to the type parameters seems to work.  For example, this compiles: def foo[P1, T](f: T forSome { type T <: P1 => Unit })(implicit tag: TypeTag[T], p1: Manifest[P1]) {}

Comment: Actually, I take it back: T ends up as Any then, and I'm back to square one.  Here's my actual use case in the event you're interested: https://gist.github.com/9840ae5a37d4b03c759a  The goal is to accept arbitrary functions as the parameter to ServerCall() and have it compile; the code above compiles, just not usage of it.

Comment: Thanks for looking some more.  My solution in the gist works fine without the overloads, and the original example was simplified to isolate this specific problem.  I capture the parameter names by passing objects that extend Function1 et al. instead of anonymous types.  So, now you can see why TypeTag[Int => Unit] will be insufficient, as what I really need is a TypeTag[MyFunction] (where MyFunction defines apply() explicitly).  Hmm, I can't see how I got TypeTag[Any] now either -- must have made a mistake.  I updated the question with more details.

Comment: It turned out the Manifests in my complex type parameter solution all ended up Manifest[Nothing], so I needed your existential type approach to get anywhere at all.  Instead of getting the TypeTag of the function, I'm just using a mirror instead, as I don't need any information from the erasure to get the parameter names.  Thanks for your help!